# Old app trying to run flash help files from local filesystem

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, flash

I have an old app that needs to be able to run flash files from the file system.  A URI like:
file:///C:/myfiles/doflash.html

I can't get anything (IE, Chrome) to load and run that.  However, if I put the same files at http://localhost/doflash.html, Chrome and IE will both work.  Is there anyway to get this to work using a file:/// URI?

Thx

Comment: Which version of Windows is in question? What do the browsers tell you when you try to access it?  is `c:\myfiles` the real path? If not, does the real path have spaces, or non-alphanumeric characters in it?  Also, have you tried using the proper Windows path separators? ie: `file:///c:\myfiles\doflash.html`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the folder to the "Trusted Location Settings" for Flash Player.  So in the case of the path above, you would add "c:\myfiles".